# Sequelize save() two times

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

is it possible use the save() function 2 times?
something like

```
const car =  await Cars.findOne({ where: { id: 1} });
car.color = 'red';
await car.save();
//some code
car.name = 'my car name';
car.save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, but it seems redundant as it will do two queries to the db. (Not the best performance)

If for some reason you need it, you would still have to add `await` in front of the second call in order to wait for the save to be completed. `await car.save()`